# Как починить java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, android

В этом коде

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.button160);
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.widget);
if(b.getText().toString().equals("ОЧИСТИТЬ ЭКРАН")) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("verbs", Context.MODE_APPEND);
    @SuppressLint("CommitPrefEdits") SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("get_text", (String) textView.getText().toString());
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, Brown.class.getName());
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
    int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(componentName);
    for (int appWidgetId : ids) {
        RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(MainActivity.this.getPackageName(), R.layout.brown);
        view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget, "");
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view);
    }
    this.stopService(new Intent(this, To_server.class));
    b.setText("ВЕРНУТЬ ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ НА ЭКРАН");
} else if (b.getText().toString().equals("ВЕРНУТЬ ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ НА ЭКРАН")) {
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, Brown.class.getName());
    AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this);
    int ids[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(componentName);
    for (int appWidgetId : ids) {
        RemoteViews view = new RemoteViews(MainActivity.this.getPackageName(), R.layout.brown);
        view.setTextViewText(R.id.widget, this.getSharedPreferences("verbs", Context.MODE_APPEND).getString("get_text", ""));
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, view);
    }
    this.startService(new Intent(this, To_server.class));
    b.setText("ОЧИСТИТЬ ЭКРАН");
}
```

появляется супер страшное исключение *java.lang.IllegalStateException* 
Вот лог, если нужно

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.glanceirregularverbs, PID: 20794
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6935)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12787)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26214)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6935) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12787) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26214) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.glanceirregularverbs.MainActivity.clean_window(MainActivity.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6935) 
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12787) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26214) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Comment: Если приведённый вами код содержит 55-ю строку MainActivity, то переменная `b` содержит `null`.

Comment: сравнивайте строковую константу со значением из надписи на кнопке, а не на оборот, меньше проверок на null нужно будет. проверяйте после файндвью, что вы действительно нашли то, что искали. не выполняйте обращение к объектам через . которые потенциально могут вернуть нулл в рантайме не проверив их.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне помогло проверить textview на null